# Calculate Time Difference in between clicks of two buttons using JS

Tags: javascript, time

I have two asp.net buttons and i want to calculate the time difference in between the clicks of the buttons using JS

Button 1 - Start
Button 2 - Next

First I got the current time on the click of the "start" button in getStartTime() function. and similarly for the second button in getEndTime() function.

For calculating the time difference I use another function calculateDifference() and call the above functions. I want to calculate the difference after the "Next" button click. The problem is getStartTime() is calculating the current time every time. How can

I store the time of button click in a variable and return it to another function?

```js
var startTime, startHour, startMin, startSec, endTime, endHour, endMin, endSec, diffTime, stTime, etTime;

//To Get the click time of Start Button(btnStart_OnClick)
function getStartTime() {
  startTime = new Date();
  startHour = startTime.getHours();
  startMin = startTime.getMinutes();
  startSec = startTime.getSeconds();
  if (startHour > 0) {
    startHour = startHour * 3600;
  }
  if (startMin > 0) {
    startMin = startMin * 60;
  }
  stTime = startHour + startMin + startSec;
  return stTime;
}
//To get the click time of Next Button
function getEndTime() {
  endTime = new Date();
  endHour = endTime.getHours();
  endMin = endTime.getMinutes();
  endSec = endTime.getSeconds();
  if (endHour > 0) {
    endHour = endHour * 3600;
  }
  if (endMin > 0) {
    endMin = endMin * 60;
  }
  etTime = endHour + endMin + endSec;
  return etTime;
}

function calculateDifference() {
  var start = getStartTime(); // On calling this function, current date is returned instead of the click time of 'Start' button
  var end = getEndTime();
  var diff = end - start;
  return diff;
}
//Button Next_OnClick
function newTimeLeft() {
  var difference = calculateDifference();
  var newTimeLeft = 1800 - difference;
  if (newTimeLeft > 0) {
    javascript_countdown.init(newTimeLeft, 'javascript_countdown_time');
  }
}
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please edit it and add the HTML and script where you assign the click handlers and your javascript_countdown

Comment: I would work in epoch ms using `Date.now()` and have a single function convert ms to formatted hours, minutes, and seconds when you are ready to display them. The start event should set a global variable declared above function scope but assigned its value in the click function - `startMs = Date.now();`, Your end function then makes an end time with `endMs=Date.now()` and subtract startMs from it. A separate function should handle milliseconds to return your formatted h:m:s string to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

If you need time differences between two button clicks you better keep track of the two timestamps. Then differentiate between two  I guess this should work -

```
let startTime, endTime;

function getStartTime() {
    startTime = new Date().getTime()
}

function getEndTime() {
    endTime = new Date().getTime()
}

function calculateDifference() {
    return startTime - endTime;
}
```

Calling `calculateDifference()` will return the time difference in milliseconds. Rest is up to you.

Hope this helps.